# Woocommerce swap product in order (subscription)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

I need to swap products in the orders (subscriptions) from PHP. E.g. I have 30 active subscriptions with order **A**, and I need to edit them to contain order **B** instead. I've tried to use WC_Subscriptions_Switcher class, but it seems like it only handles the subscriptions changes (not triggers them) and checkout and adds users the ability to switch their subscriptions manually. I've tried to change values in the `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table, but there are too many dependencies (e.g. product variations, order titles), I'm afraid I may leave something unchanged and it may cause whole lot of problems. Can't google anything quite useful, maybe someone have ideas how to implement this?

Comment: I have same suggestion: like my user have purchase service for puppy for 4 month. After complete 6 month how to swap in another service (subscription) I have used with woocommerce product addons.

Any possiblity?

I have check your current process in swap in same group or varision product but how to move on another subscription (simple sub.).